# Can someone explain why "lo" is required in this sentence?

Tags: gramática

Can someone please explain why **lo** is needed in this sentence? It confuses me and I can't find anything to explain it.

> El calpulli **lo** formaban personas que estaban unidas familiarmente

Thanks.

Comment: **[calpulli](https://dle.rae.es/calpulli)**: Clan o división que constituía la unidad fundamental de la sociedad azteca.

Comment: I haven´t found that sentence online. but it's very similar to this one: "Las personas que estaban unidas familiarmente formaban un calpulli". This don't answer your question but maybe you have missed "personas": "El calpulli lo formaban personas que estaban unidas familiarmente".

Comment: @RubioRic good catch.

Comment: @mdewey Thanks :-)

Comment: https://spanish.kwiziq.com/revision/grammar/repetition-of-direct-object-pronouns

Comment: @iBug The site you quoted is misleading. OP might think that saying "Personas que estaban unidas familiarmente LO formaban el/al capulli" is grammatical, and it is not. The site you quoted refers to duplication of animate direct objects, which is a completely different case.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If the sentence, as RubioRic rightly suggested, is:

- El calpulli lo formaban personas que estaban unidas familiarmente.

"lo" is an obligatory duplicate direct object. This occurs, among other cases, when the direct object is placed before the verb.

The normal word order is:

- Personas que estaban unidas familiarmente (I would have said "mediante/por lazos familiares") formaban **el calpulli** => Personas que estaban unidas familiarmente LO formaban.

Now, if the direct object "el calpulli" is placed before the verb, the rule transcribed below applies:

> 5.2. Si el complemento tónico no es un pronombre personal y aparece antepuesto al verbo, también es obligatoria la coaparición del pronombre átono, tanto si el complemento es directo como indirecto: A tu hermano lo vi en el cine (no *A tu hermano vi en el cine); La tarta la llevo yo (no *La tarta llevo yo); A mi madre le he dicho la verdad (no *A mi madre he dicho la verdad); A Juan le han denegado la beca (no *A Juan han denegado la beca). Deben diferenciarse estas construcciones, con el complemento tónico antepuesto y coaparición del pronombre átono, de aquellas en que la anteposición del complemento es enfática, contrastiva, en las que no coaparece el pronombre átono: Un libro te daré, y no dos (y no *Un libro te lo daré, y no dos).

According to this rule ([Source](https://www.rae.es/dpd/pronombres%20personales%20%C3%A1tonos#52)), the direct object needs to be duplicated by means of the pronoun "lo" (or "la", "los", "las")

- La tarta **la** llevo yo (A variant of: Yo llevo la tarta).
- El calpulli **lo** formaban esas personas (A variant of: Esas personas formaban el calpulli).

It is worth stressing that the original sentence "El calpulli lo formaban ..." flows much better than "Personas ... formaban el calpulli" because the subject "Personas ..." is too long and is indeterminate, so its initial position would sound unnatural.

Note: As stated by DPD under 5.2. above, when contrast needs to be expressed the duplication of the direct object does not take place. One important detail is omitted there, and that is that the preposed object is usually unspecified. The example provided there is:

- Un libro te daré, y no dos. (contrastive structure)

Here follow some more examples to prove the point of this note:

- El libro te **lo** presto, pero la revista no. (contrastive structure with specified object: duplication)
- Leche compré, pero yogurt no. (contrastive structure with unspecified object: no duplication)
- La leche **la** tomo, pero el yogurt no. (contrastive structure with specified object: duplication)

Sometimes indetermination is conveyed by the plural form:

- Consejos vendo, pero para mí no tengo. (unspecified object: no duplication)
- Malas noticias me traes. (unspecified object: no duplication)

Comment: Thank you for the reply.  I understand this now.

Comment: Great answer! :-)

Comment: I'm curious if [this question](/q/2104/17109) is essentially the same.

Comment: @iBug It is related but not exactly the same. The question you brought up has to do with object duplication in general (actually, duplication of the indirect object), but this phenomenon of a preposed direct object that usually renders duplication necessary is a particular case not dealt with in the other Q&A.